# Set "text" property to a CustomValidator in ASP.NET (Webforms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

In my .aspx page, I've a ValidationSummary where I put error messages returned by my Business Layer.

The error messages appears in the summary, ok, but not the "*" that normally appears next to the field =(

In the code behind, I've the following code:

```
CustomValidator cv = new CustomValidator();
cv.ControlToValidate = field.ID;
cv.ErrorMessage = "Error Message";
cv.Text = "*";
cv.IsValid = false;
Page.Validators.Add(cv);
```

Basically, I want to add the "*" next to each incorrect field, but without creating CustomValidators for each one... is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ErrorMessage` property will be displayed in the `ValidationSummary` while the `Text` property will be displayed where the `Validator` is. To meet your requirement, you need to put the `CustomValidators` beside those controls you want to validate.

Since all the validators are generated in code behind, you need to add those validators to a proper position using `Page.Controls.AddAt(int indexer, Control child)` because `CustomValidator` is also a control.

When you add the validator beside the textbox, you can get the exact index by following code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="just a post back" />
</form>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CustomValidator v = new CustomValidator();
     v.ErrorMessage = "error!";
     v.Text = "****";
     v.ControlToValidate = "tb";
     int index = form1.Controls.IndexOf(tb);
     form1.Controls.AddAt(index + 1, v);
}
```

NOTE: if you put the textbox in a PlaceHolder or some containers, you can't get it by `form1.Controls` because `Container.Controls` returns the 1st level child controls only.

Comment: Thank you! The "index" helped me =)